# не срабатывает проверка select в плагине validator

Tags: php, java, jquery

здравствуйте, не получается сделать проверку select через плагин jquery validator...

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="AddNews">
   <select name="search_cat" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

код validator

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
$( "#AddNews" ).validate( {
    rules: {
        search_cat: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        search_cat: "Please select category"
    },
    errorElement: "em",
    errorPlacement: function ( error, element ) {
        // Add the `help-block` class to the error element
        error.addClass( "help-block" );

        if ( element.prop( "type" ) === "checkbox" ) {
            error.insertAfter( element.parent( "label" ) );
        } else {
            error.insertAfter( element );
        }
    },
    highlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
        $( element ).parents( ".col-sm-5" ).addClass( "has-error" ).removeClass( "has-success" );
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $( element ).parents( ".col-sm-5" ).addClass( "has-success" ).removeClass( "has-error" );
    }
} );
  } );
```

такой метод к сожалению не помогает и такой тоже ...

```
rules: {
        search_cat: {required:true}
    },
```

не понимаю как еще сделать